# CONCATENATE(IF()) - how to simplify current solution?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, vba

My data looks like this:

```
     ColumnName    PrimaryKey
1    ID               Y
2    JOB_NAME         N
3    JOB_DESC         N
4    START            N
5    END              N
...
```

I'm looking to list all columns that are primary keys - so, all columns where PrimaryKey = "Y" - in one cell, with "+" signs inbetween each returned row for ColumnName. This is the code I have so far:

```
=CONCATENATE((IF(C1="Y",B1,"")),(IF(C2="Y",B2,"")),(IF(C3="Y",B3,"")),(IF(C4="Y",B4,"")),(IF(C5="Y",B5,"")))
```

It gets the job done, but since I have over 50 rows in the ColumnName column, it ought to be a bit more concise.

Comment: Why is this tagged with SQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an interesting **NON VBA** way to do it :) You **may** still want to go with other VBA answer.

Let's say your range looks like this

[image]

I could think of two ways. **You may like way 2 better** :). I will mention both

---

**WAY 1**

---

Now type this in cell `C1` or whatever cell you want the output in (**Do not press ENTER Key**).

```
=CONCATENATE(TRANSPOSE(IF(B1:B5="Y",A1:A5,"+")))
```

[image]

Now select the formula as shown in the image below and press <kbd>F9</kbd>

[image]

You will get something like this. You may delete consecutive `"+","+"` here or you can remove them later in the end.

[image]

Delete the `{` and `}` from the formula and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You will get this

[image]

Convert the cell formula to value and do a replace on `++` till the time no more `++` is left.

---

**WAY 2**

---

Type this formula in cell `C1`

```
=IF(B1="Y",A1,"")
```

and type this formula in `C2`

```
=IF(AND(C1<>"",B2<>"N"),C1&"+"&IF(B2="Y",A2,""),IF(B2="Y",A2,C1))
```

Simply drag it down.

[image]

Comment: Way 2 is definitely simpler than way1.

Comment: @SiddharthRout - is there any way to convert the array of strings created in Way 1 into a string, without manually resolving that expression and removing the braces? This to me is one of the strictest limitations on array manipulation in Excel, which pushes otherwise simple tasks into requiring VBA.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon `without manually resolving that expression and removing the braces?` unfortunately no. And hence I like Way2 more then way1

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a User Defined Function to address. You can enter the function `ExtractPK` into a cell and get the result there, or you can process it as part of a VBA script. The function takes two arguments. First, enter the range with the values to be concatenated. Next, enter the joining string (a plus sign in your case).

To use, enter the following code into a VBA standard module:

```
Function ExtractPK(rng As Range, sJoiner As String) As String
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim sOutput As String

    sOutput = ""

    For Each cel In rng
        If cel.Offset(, 1).Value = "Y" Then
            sOutput = sOutput & sJoiner & cel.Value
        End If
    Next cel

    ExtractPK = Mid(sOutput, 2)
End Function
```

Next, enter the function into the cell of choice. Let's say your data is in cells `A1:A10`, with the Primary Key indicator in cells `B1:B10`, enter this function into cell `C1`:
`=ExtractPK(A1:A10,"+")`

Let me know if that works and also if you need additional support.

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding correctly

```html
drop table #temp
go

select * into #temp from 
(values
      ('ID', 'Y' )
     ,('JOB_NAME', 'N' )
     ,('JOB_DESC', 'N' )
     ,('START', 'N' )
     ,('END', 'N' )
  ,('ID2', 'Y' )
  ,('ID3', 'Y' )
  ,('ID4', 'Y' )
) as temp (cl1, pk)


declare @pks varchar(500) = ''

select @pks += cl1 + ' + ' + char(10) from #temp where pk = 'Y'

select @pks

-- it returns 
--ID + 
--ID2 + 
--ID3 + 
--ID4 +
```

Comment: This is an `Excel` question !